# System.in and Scanner object

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, system, bufferedinputstream

I am having a problem to understand what *System.in* do. All I understand is that it's a data field in the System class and that it's declaration is:

```
public static final InputStream in
```

It's declared final so it cannot be changed.
As mentioned in the Oracle source they say that "in" is the "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.
What does this exactly mean?

When I write the following code :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

That *Scanner* object is ready to scan what's in *System.in*, but nothing shows up in the CMD.

Another point is that when I try to print *System.in*, I end up with an output like:

> java.io.BufferedInputStream@15db9742

Can anyone please explain the whole process and what's the exact job of both *System.in* and *Scanner* class!

Comment: `System.in` read from file descriptor 0 which is also standard input.  This could be redirected from a file or read from the console.  Can you clarify what your doubt is, perhaps its not as complicated as you imagine it might be.

Comment: System.in is like an object ( stream more likely ), we don't write what we want on it it just reads what we wrote from the CMD , right ? then Scanner translate the whole stream into int or double and so on

Comment: Correct, the input comes via the OS rather than using CMD as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.in` is a `BufferedInputStream`, such a `Stream` can be any input stream (for instance a network socket, or a file), but also the standard input channel `stdin`.

`stdin` is the content you type in the command line, so obviously, it doesn't show anything.

When you create a `Scanner` as shown in your question, you feed the standard input channel to that `Scanner`, but the scanner won't do anything until it is asked to. A scanner is a *wrapper*: a construct that makes it easier (more convenient) to parse input from the `stdin`. It does not offer additional functionality in the sense you can do all what a scanner does by yourself, but it is way easier to use a scanner if you want to *parse* for instance integers from the `stdin`.

So when you for instance type:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int val = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println(2*val);
```

It will wait until you input a line, parse it to an integer and print the double of the inputted value on the standard output channel (`stdout`).

---

A few concluding notes:

> `System.in` is not `final`, you can use `System.setIn` to set another input stream as the standard input string. For instance a file or a network socket.
>   The default `System.in` can also take input from for instance a file or a *pipe* if you for instance call the program as `java -jar program.jar < inputfile`.

Comment: so is the ( stdin ) the same as ( System.in ) with a different pronunciation ?

Comment: Well `System.in` (if not set to anthying else), is the Java equivalent of `stdin`, a virtual file that reads from the terminal/command line/...

Comment: ah , so System.in is something that we declare so that i can write whatever i want through the command line and then Scanner's job is to translate what in the System.in .. am i right ?

Comment: I think that's more or less correct yes. If you mean with *"we"*, the user.

Comment: we programmers declare it so that user can write whatever he wants throughout this input stream and it doesn't wait for an input until scanner is asked to

Comment: Well the `stdin` and the `Scanner` run asynchrone. It can take a long time before the `Scanner` tries to parse input. If in the mean time, a user already provides input, the `Scanner` will parse that input first. If not, it **blocks** until the user provides the input.

Answer (score 3):

`Scanner` is a class in `java.util` package .

When you write `Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in)` you are trying to read the input from the `"standard" input stream`. Mainly `System.in` is used for reading the input from the console

Scanner holds the program execution until the input arrives, that is how it is meant to be.

And your question that when you print the `System.in` you end end up with a output like `java.io.BufferedInputStream@15db9742`, this output is called as the object `hash code` and you are likely to get this kind of output if you try to print an object.
Here you are getting the hash code because you are trying to print an entire stream.

Comment: Not entirely true. If no input arrives and you can `Scanner.nextInt`, it will block the program execution until such input arrives.